# ASP.NET MVC 3 Validating ComplexModel.EntityCollection.Property1 for only the first X items in the collection with Custom ValidationAttribute

Tags: entity-framework, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, collections, validationattribute

My model is described below. I'd like to only require a subset of Reference fields for the first 2 items in the Application.References collection. I'd like this to occur on both client side and server side validation. I have a working method that I'll describe below, but I feel the client side is rather kludgey, so I wonder if there might be a better way to handle this. I'd like to be generic if possible, cause I have a few other collections in the Application object to validate a subset of.

**EF Model**

```
public class Application
{
    //...EF framework code...
    public EntityCollection<Reference> References
    {
        //get, set
    }
}

public partial class Reference : EntityObject
{
    public global::System.String FullName
    {
        //get, set
    }

    public global::System.String Relationship
    {
        //get, set
    }

    public global::System.String PhoneNumber
    {
        //get, set
    }

    public global::int? RelationshipLength //radio button
    {
        //get, set
    }

    public global::int? ReferenceType //radio button
    {
        //get, set
    }
}
```

**ReferenceMetaData.cs**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ReferenceMetadata))]
public partial class Reference
{
}

public class ReferenceMetadata
{
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "N/A")]
    [DisplayName("Full Name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "N/A")]
    [DisplayName("Reference Type")]
    public string ReferenceType { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "N/A")]
    [DisplayName("How long have you known this person?")]
    public string RelationshipLength { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "N/A")]
    [DisplayName("Relationship")]
    public string Relationship { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "N/A")]
    [DisplayName("Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    //...more properites
}
```

I'm currently using Steven Sanderson's RuleException and RulesViolationExceptionExtensions from [Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865) to do server side validation manually as follows:

```
public static class ApplicationBusinessLogic
{
    public static void RunServerValidation(Application app)
    {
        var errors = new RulesException<Application>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.References.ElementAt(i).FullName))
                errors.ErrorFor(x => x.References.ElementAt(i).FullName, "The Full Name for a first and second reference are required.");
            if (app.References.ElementAt(i).ReferenceType == null)
                errors.ErrorFor(x => x.References.ElementAt(i).ReferenceType, "The Reference Type for a first and second reference are required.");
            if (app.References.ElementAt(i).RelationshipLength == null)
                errors.ErrorFor(x => x.References.ElementAt(i).RelationshipLength, "The Relationship Length for a first and second reference are required.");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.References.ElementAt(i).Relationship))
                errors.ErrorFor(x => x.References.ElementAt(i).Relationship, "The Relationship for a first and second reference are required.");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.References.ElementAt(i).Phone))
                errors.ErrorFor(x => x.References.ElementAt(i).Relationship, "The Phone Number for a first and second reference are required.");
        }

        if (errors.Errors.Any())
            throw errors;
    }

}
```

I simply call that RunServerValidation method from the controller, catch the exceptions, and then copy them to ModelState. It works fine, but I'm not sure how to handle this in the client side. If I used the [Required] metadata, all the 3 items in the collection will have those fields required. I just want 2 out of 3.

The kludgey way I've hooked up client validation is by specifying the data-val and data-val-required attributes in the view while rendering the inputs like so:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Application.References[" + i + "]";    
    <h3>Reference @i</h3>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Application.References.ElementAt(i).FullName)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Application.References.ElementAt(i).FullName)
    </div>                
    <div class="editor-field">   
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Application.References.ElementAt(i).FullName, new { maxlength = "100", data_val="true", data_val_required="The Full Name for a first and second reference are required." })
    </div>
    @* and so on for other properties... *@
}
```

It works, but this can't be ideal. I've thought maybe I could make a generic ValidationAttribute, but I'd imagine that'd be complex. I was thinking `[RequiredFieldsForFirstXCollectionItems(FirstXItems=2, Fields= new [] {"FullName", "ReferenceType" /* etc */})]` on the Application.References member, but I'm not sure how to do that in a generic way. Am I on the right track with that thought though? Then I could implement client side and server side that way, but it would be pretty complex code I think.

**Update 04/26/2011:**

I think it's probably better for me to add the client side validation using the jquery.Validation plugin in the $(document).ready function, rather than putting the data-val and data-val-required html5 attributes on the input tags. Then at least I have a centralized place for my client validation. Here's what I've done:

```
@*End of Razor View file*@
<script type="text/javascript>
     function addValidationRules() {
        //references
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            $("#Application_References_" + i + "__FullName").rules("add", {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "The Full Name for a first and second reference are required."
                }
            });
            //etc. for other properties
        }//end for-loop
    }//end addValidationRules()
    $(document).ready(function () {
        addValidationRules();
        //more js code...
    });
</script>
```

Of course, when I get to using resource files for the error messages, it might get a little hairy if I decide to move the javascript into a .js file. I think if I keep the function in the view I should be able to read the resource file as needed.